# how to check the textbox text if it's value is exist in a option value text?

Tags: jquery

```
var appendvalue = $('#edi_autor').val(); {
    var hasOption = $('#authors option[value="' + appendvalue + '"]');
    if (hasOption.length != 0) {
        alert('Already exits');
        return true;
    }
});
```

What mistakes with this jquery code?

Comment: Improve code formatting, please. Where do `{` in the end of the first line, and `});` in the end belong?

Comment: Can you add complete code, better to add live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Add proper opening and closing tags!

Comment: '#authors option'    Why is there a space in there?  If really space need quotes around both words.

Comment: Parenthesis mismatch?

Comment: I'd try this so your code doesn't error out if something isn't found. ````if ( hasOption && hasOption.length != 0 ) {```` Also, you should consider checking your Javascript console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var appendvalue = $('#edi_autor').val();
    $("#sel option").each(function()
    {
        if ($(this).text()==appendvalue)
        {
            alert('Exists');
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/surajmahajan007/6o8a42nL/